# Printing out values using pointers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcmp

I have a sorted array of some indeterminate number of variables and counts thereof.  I need to build a string like so:

```
Attribute[0]: p=2, e=8
```

My issue is the array is actually a pointer, and I don't want to use a loop of fixed length, so the only solution I see is to use an array pointer.

```
void printArray(Node_ptr node){
    int count=0; //character count
    char *temp= node->attributes; //duplicate attribute array

    char cur; //current char
    char *outputCat= emalloc(150); //concatenate counts to a single string

    strcpy(outputCat, "Attribute %d counts are: ");
    qsort(temp, lineCount, sizeof(char), compare); //sort the array

    while ((temp) != NULL){
        cur= *temp;
        ++temp;
        if (strcmp(&cur, temp)==0) //if characters are same
            count++; 
        else { //build reporting string
            strcat(outputCat, &cur);
            strcat(outputCat, "= ");
            sprintf(outputCat, "%d  ", count);
            count=0;
        }
    }
    free(outputCat);
}
```

The issue here is `strcmp(&cur, ++temp)==0` is returning false every time, even when I see their values in the debugger.  Because of this, the else conditional is constantly being built up and throws a segfault after a number of iterations.

Two questions:

1- What can make `strcmp` return non-zero even when identical values are entered?
2- What can I do to fix the code?

Comment: You shouldn't use `strcmp` or `strcat` on a `char`. Both arguments must be NULL terminated character arrays. That in itself could cause a segfault. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if fixing that fixes your code completely.

Comment: brain fart.  I forgot characters can be compared directly without a function.  Changing that didn't do anything, however, since the comparison always gets skipped over, even when `cur` is 'e', as is `*temp`

Comment: well seth, that's the answer isn't it? You should re-submit as an answer so Jason can accept it.

Comment: Update your code so we can see what still isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your line:

```
strcmp(&cur, temp)
```

`cur` is a `char` declared locally, and therefore, `&cur` is just some location on the stack, and rather meaningless in this context.

I believe you mean to check if the current-character `cur` is the same as the next character `*temp`.
This would look like:

```
if (cur == *temp) //if characters are same
    count++;
```

Next, I would look at massively simplify your output section:

```
sprintf(outputCat, "%c = %d", *cur, count);  // e.g.   "e = 8"
count=0;
```

And finally, I doubt your loop will ever terminate, as it continues to do `temp++`, while `temp != NULL`.
I believe you intend to check the VALUE stored at the pointer `temp`.
`*temp` should be properly checked against '\0', instead of NULL.
(\0 and NULL happen to have the same value, but they should **not** be treated the same semantically)

```
while (*temp != '\0'){
```

**P.S.**   Your simple, but excellent comment "// if characters are same" was extremely helpful for me to understand your code.   This is an excellent case of short, meaningful comments being **INVALUABLE**.  Thank you.

---

*(Hopefully final edit)*
In total, the changes I recommend look like:

```
void printArray(Node_ptr node){
    int count=0; //character count
    char *temp= node->attributes; //duplicate attribute array

    char cur; //current char
    char *outputCat= emalloc(150); //concatenate counts to a single string

    strcpy(outputCat, "Attribute %d counts are: ");
    qsort(temp, lineCount, sizeof(char), compare); //sort the array

    while (*temp != '\0'){
        cur= *temp;
        ++temp;
        if (cur == *temp) //if characters are same
            count++; 
        else { //build reporting string
            sprintf(outputCat, "%c = %d", *cur, count);  // e.g.   "e = 8"
            count=0;
        }
    }
    free(outputCat);
}
```

How's that work out for you?

Comment: The `cur==*temp) line was the key.  Right now, I have a couple changes to make, because the number of unique data points varies depending on the array.  With both my original code and this one, it works for the first set of values, but if cur changes from e to p, the code doesn't adjust for it.